# Running Mavenized ::Project Maven Studio Goal Post Error

Tags: eclipse, maven, mule-studio

I've got Maven installed. At command prompt `mvn - version` shows the right information. In Mule, the "Test Maven Configuration".

I try to Mavenize a project, or create a project with Maven from the start, or update project dependencies, I get the following Error on Console

```
The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.*****.mule:******-system-service:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT (C:\GIT\mainframe-system-service\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: mule @ line 8, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

POM File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule sample-service Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.8.5</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
        <munit.version>1.3.7</munit.version>
        <mule.munit.support.version>3.8.6</mule.munit.support.version>
        <com.ibm.wmq.version>7.5.0.2</com.ibm.wmq.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>edi-module-x12</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-anypoint-mq-ee</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.utils</groupId>
                            <artifactId>munit-synchronize-module</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>azure-storage-connector</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
            <version>10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm/com.ibm.mq -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
            <version>${com.ibm.wmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.commonservices</artifactId>
            <version>${com.ibm.wmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.headers</artifactId>
            <version>${com.ibm.wmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
            <version>${com.ibm.wmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
            <version>${com.ibm.wmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
            <version>${com.ibm.wmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId>
            <version>${com.ibm.wmq.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>edi-module-x12</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-anypoint-mq-ee</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-db</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-synchronize-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-wmq-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-email</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>03b2fd5d-0ae4-4388-b2a3-d760d568ff1c</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-auth-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-schedulers</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-cors-gw</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Repository</id>
            <name>Mycompany Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/03b2fd5d-0ae4-4388-b2a3-d760d568ff1c/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mule-ee-releases</id>
            <name>MuleEE Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I checked JDK is correctly set. I also checked with Maven, it's also correctly configured.

Comment: Hi Pavan, you'll likely want to share your `pom.xml` so that others will be able to help you!

Answer (score -1):

Regarding to [Your new Maven friend – the Mule Maven Plugin 2.0](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/biz/mule/your-new-maven-friend-the-mule-maven-plugin-2-0/) and [Mule Plugin for Maven](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.7/mule-maven-plugin), we should configure the `pluginRepositories` as the following:-

```xml
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mule-public</id>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

#### Note

We can browse it online by visiting

- [Index of /repositories/releases/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-app-maven-plugin](https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-app-maven-plugin/)